# PHP Object oriented array output

Tags: php, arrays, object, echo

I did not make the array myself, so I honestly have no clue of how to echo an specific variable in the array.

This is my code:

```
foreach($server_players as $data) {
    print_r($data);
}
```

Which outputs

```
SteamPlayer Object
(
    [clientPort:SteamPlayer:private] => 
    [connectTime:SteamPlayer:private] => 76.529731750488
    [extended:SteamPlayer:private] => 
    [id:SteamPlayer:private] => 0
    [ipAddress:SteamPlayer:private] => 
    [loss:SteamPlayer:private] => 
    [name:SteamPlayer:private] => Din yndlings Slyngel <3
    [ping:SteamPlayer:private] => 
    [rate:SteamPlayer:private] => 
    [realId:SteamPlayer:private] => 
    [score:SteamPlayer:private] => 0
    [state:SteamPlayer:private] => 
    [steamId:SteamPlayer:private] => 
)
```

var_dump output

```
object(SteamPlayer)[14]
  private 'clientPort' => null
  private 'connectTime' => float 6556.9243164062
  private 'extended' => boolean false
  private 'id' => int 0
  private 'ipAddress' => null
  private 'loss' => null
  private 'name' => string 'Alfred' (length=6)
  private 'ping' => null
  private 'rate' => null
  private 'realId' => null
  private 'score' => int 2
  private 'state' => null
  private 'steamId' => null
```

I want to take the player name of indevidual players, but i don't know how.

this is kinda what i want to do

```
foreach($server_players as $data) {
    echo "Player name: ".$data['name:SteamPlayer:private'];
}
```

Comment: what about `var_dump($data)`.

Comment: In fact thats its a object and not a array you propably have to go with `$data->name`. I dont know if this works but I know you have to use `->`operator in objects. And I guess you cant access it becaus its private.

Comment: That particular property is private, which means you wont be able to access it unless the object has a method to access it. In the documentation for these players you're using does it mention getName or something similar? (that's just a guess it may be called something else)

Comment: Thank you @RahilWazir, it allready has bin told twice ^^

Comment: Next question, please provide helpers with more information. The given answere was just a guess on a may used library. In this case he was right but keep it in mind for further questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($server_players as $data) {
  echo "Player name: ".$data->getName();
}
```

Comment: so you think he has getters ?

Comment: Yah. I was kind of assuming he was using this library: https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser-php/blob/04a1345ff4fa29a02d6923e8ed622777978040e9/lib/SteamCondenser/Servers/SteamPlayer.php

Comment: Didn't think it mattered. I didn't know I needed getters :/

Comment: @sofeb you dont need if or publics but on privates you do.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are in the correct path but as your output has indicated:

```
[name:SteamPlayer:private]
```

So you will need to find out if you have getters in the object OR you will have to change some of the fields to public.

If you cannot do either of those things, then there is no straightforward way to do this given the info you've provided.

Comment: haha alright, I was just trying to go by the information provided.

Comment: He didnt give us all information, some one just... guessed right ^^

Answer (score -1):

You can try doing it like this

```
foreach($server_players as $data) {
    echo "Player name: ".$data->name;
}
```

Comment: `var_dump` shows they are private properties. So you cannot access it like this.